# Почему Session не дружит с UTF-8?

Tags: ansi, сессия, utf-8, php

Заметил странную штуку.
Есть файл в кодировке ANSI, в котором объявляется сессия. И все ок.
Если этот файл перевести в UTF-8, то вылезает

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent...

Кто знает, почему оно так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо сохранить документ в формате UTF-8 без BOM. Справится с этим может тот же самый Notepad++ и убедитесь что session_start(); поставлена самой первой строчкой. А суть ошибки заключается в том, что при обычном сохранении UTF-8, есть такая штука как Byte Order Mask, которая добавляет тот самый несчастный символ в начало файла.

Comment: Да, это я понял. Но возникает другая проблема. Если преобразовываю в UTF-8 без DOM, то появляются краказябры. (В meta кодировка указывается как UTF-8)

Comment: В самом Notepad++?
Скопируйте оттуда весь текст, удалите его, нажмите в сохранить без BOM, затем вставьте обратно и ещё раз сохраните. Всё получится

Comment: Все так делал, но ничего не меняется. При сохранении без BOM сбивается кодировка почему-то.

Comment: в html5 при использовании кодировки utf-8
"<meta charset="utf-8">"
в css при использовании кодировки utf-8
"@charset "utf-8";"
если все написано правильно - кодировка не сбивается

Answer (score 1):

Добавте это в начале файла с кодом

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8');
?>
```